# Turn off bell in tmux but keep hook

Tags: tmux

I have a custom bell command:

```
set -g monitor-bell on
set -g bell-action current
set-hook -g alert-bell 'set -g status-bg "#901010" ; run-shell "sleep 0.1s" ; set -g status-bg colour8'
```

Unfortunately, this does not suppress the beep. In order to do that, I would have to either set `monitor-bell` off or `bell-action` off (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22073328/1078199)). However, then my `alert-bell` hook never fires.

I have tried removing any existing hooks before adding my own:

```
set-hook -u alert-bell
set-hook -gu alert-bell
```

How do I suppress the audible beep but still keep the `alert-bell` hook in tmux 2.7?

Comment: What terminal emulator are you using?  It may be easier to disable/ignore the audible bell there.

Comment: `urxvt`. There is an option to use a visual bell instead of an audio one, which is also not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set -g visual-bell on
```

This will cause `tmux` to flash up a message ("Bell in current window") instead of telling the terminal to beep.  The message may obscure the status bar changes you've made with your own hook.

From the manual:

> **visual-bell [on | off | both]**
>
> If on, a message is shown on a bell in a window for which the
>      **monitor-bell** window option is enabled instead of it being
>      passed through to the terminal (which normally makes a
>      sound). [...]

Comment: How do I disable the beep and the message, but keep the hook?

Comment: That doesn't appear to be possible with current tmux (there's no "neither" option for visual-bell).  You could set the "display-time" to 1, which would make all messages disappear after 1 millisecond (0 means until next keypress).

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of the `visual-bell` message by quickly hiding it from inside the `alert-bell` hook, using `display -d1` (which shows an empty message for one millisecond).

For example, here’s a hook which will blink the status line by setting its background color to white for a tenth of a second (though you could change any kind of style that you’d like).

```
set -g visual-bell on
set-hook -g alert-bell {
    display -d1
    set status-style bg=white
    run -b -d.1 -C {
        set -u status-style
    }
}
```

Note that the `set` commands sets and unsets the `status-style` *session* option (which overrides any *global* option for as long as it’s set). This means any customizations you’ve done to you status line with global options (`set -g`) are unaffected by this hook.

Answer (score 0):

I iterated on the previous example and this is the result:

```
set -g monitor-bell on
set -g visual-bell on
set-hook -g alert-bell {
  display-message -d1
  setw @bell_flag 1
  run -b -d.5 -C {
    setw @bell_flag 0
  }
}
set-hook -g pane-focus-in {
  setw @bell_flag 0
}
```

Then, I use my own variable @bell_flag instead of the builtin variable window_bell_flag.